# Aggregate documentation comments from multiple scripts into README?

Tags: python, documentation-generation

After having written some python scripts with comments for documentation inside, is it a good idea and possible to aggregate the documentation comments from multiple scripts into some standalone documentation file such as README?

Furthermore, is it possible to aggregate them in some markup format such as Markdown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend looking into [Epydoc](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/) and also [Sphinx-Doc](http://sphinx-doc.org/).

Epydoc especially does exactly what you are asking for as stated on their website and as per my experience working with it:

> Epydoc is a tool for generating API documentation for Python modules, based on their docstrings.

Comment: In my experience, Sphinx tends to be much more commonly used and can pull docs from docstrings as well using the autodoc feature (http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html).